# How to add day to date in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-sql

I am writing this code. Here dt is input into the function, as well as someint. The column Exp is a T-SQL date column, which comes as a DateTime through Linq.

```
return (from a in dataContext.TableOfA
       where a.name == "Test" &&
       a.Exp.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(Someint)) >= new DateTimeOffset(dt)
       select a).First();
```

In C#, you can add a double as a day to a date time. Meaning you can add 1.5 days. In T-SQL you can only add 1 day, then 12 hours. You must add an int for each part. So when Linq translates AddDays to T-SQL, it converts my number of days to milliseconds, and adds those. This allows it to give all the precision the double gives C#.

Here's the rub. When this gets to SQL, I get the error:

> The datepart millisecond is not
>   supported by date function dateadd for
>   data type date

Basically you can't add milliseconds to a date. Well no kidding. But how do I get something that translates here? I want to add int days to a date. Is the only want to do this to add the negative of them to the other guy I am comparing against? What if I wanted to compare to columns while adding to one?

**Update 1**

> Keith wrote, A command like
>   datepart(millisecond, 10000, myDate)
>   has been supported in T-SQL since at
>   least SQL Server 2000. This error
>   suggests that whatever database you
>   are using does not support the
>   millisecond date part, which seems
>   strange to me.

Please note I am using SQL Server 2008. It is not supported on the DATE data type. It is supported on datetime.

Comment: A command like datepart(millisecond, 10000, myDate) has been supported in T-SQL since at least SQL Server 2000.  This error suggests that whatever database you are using does not support the millisecond date part, which seems strange to me.

Comment: It is not supported on the DATE data type. It is supported on datetime.

Comment: That makes more sense.  Well if you have control over the DB design, the simple solution would be to change this column from a DATE to a DATETIME then.  Obviously if you're asking this question though, this is not something you have control over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just changed the column back to a DateTime.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the Entity Framework, use the System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions as below:

```
c.CMT_TS > System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddDays(e.Call.CALL_TS, 1)
```

Comment: In 2019, `EntityFunctions` is deprecated. Please use `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Create a new `DateTime` object and use `AddDays` method after that:

```
new DateTime(t.Key.Year,t.Key.Month,T.Key.Day).AddDays(xx)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use: `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddDays(YourDateTime, NumberOfDays)` This function will be translated to valid SQL Query. Class `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityFunctions` which also contains AddDays function is obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the call to `AddDays` from the SQL part to the .NET part:

```
a.Exp.Value >= new DateTimeOffset(dt).AddDays(-Convert.ToDouble(Someint))
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this scenario is mostly fixed in .NET 4.5.

However, if you write:

```
var activeProducts = from p in db.Products where DateTime.Now() <= p.EndDate.Date.AddDays(7) select p;
```

You will get the same error message as described in the OP.

But, if you write:

```
var activeProducts = from p in db.Products where DateTime.Now() <= p.EndDate.AddDays(7) select p;
```

Then you can enter the land of milk and honey.  Note that I did not call .Date on the database's DateTime representation.  This seems to be an edge case missing test coverage by the LINQ 2 SQL framework in 4.5

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5.1 and both scenarios you have give me the "not supported by LINQ" error

Comment: It says it is supported here so I need more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [SqlMethods.DateDiffDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.datediffday.aspx) method, if you're trying to compare two dates

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem with that query.

```
return (from a in dataContext.TableOfA
       where a.name == "Test" &&
       DbFunctions.AddHours(DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(
 a.Exp.Value.Year,a.Exp.Value.Month,a.Exp.Value.Day,a.Exp.Value.Hour,a.Exp.Value.Minute,
a.Exp.Value.Millisecond),Someint) >=     
DbFunctions.CreateDateTimeOffset(dt.Year,dt.Month,dt.Day,dt.Hour,dt.Minute,dt.Millisecond,0)
       select a).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing your own user-defined function that basically takes in an int (for number of days) and date, returns the results of a dateadd()?  Then pull that into the LINQ class in your project.  Then, instead of calling .AddDate(), call your UDF - this will allow you to keep everything in your LINQ query without having to manually piece together a SQLCommand.

Answer (score -2):

May be good idea if you would first change your Sql query to Linq and process linq query instead.

Just add ToList() or limit record

```
return (from a in dataContext.TableOfA.ToList()
   where a.name == "Test" &&
   a.Exp.Value.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(Someint)) >= new DateTimeOffset(dt)
   select a).First();
```

So once you have all your stuff in Linq then you can process more effectivly I think.

Cheers