# Best way to get record counts grouped by month, adjusted for time zone, using SQL or LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for the most efficient way to suck out a series of monthly counts of records in my database, but adjusting for time zone, since the times are actually stored as UTC. I would like my result set to be a series of objects that include month, year and count.

I have LINQ to SQL objects that looks something like this:

```
public class MyRecord {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
   public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not opposed to using straight SQL, but LINQ to SQL would at least keep the code a lot more clean. The time zone adjustment is available as an integer (-5, for example). Again, the result set what I'm looking for is objects containing the month, year and count, all integers.

Any suggestions? I can think of several ways to do it straight, but not with a time zone adjustment.

EDIT: The answer below got me headed in the right direction. This is what I ultimately ended up with:

```
var counts = _context.MyRecord
    .Select(r => new {original = r.TimeStamp, adjusted = TimeAdjust.GetAdjustedTime(Config.TimeZoneAdjustment, r.TimeStamp)}).ToArray()
    .GroupBy(r => new {r.adjusted.Month, r.adjusted.Year})
    .Select(g => new MonthCount { Count = g.Count(), Year = g.Key.Year, Month = g.Key.Month })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Year).ThenByDescending(g => g.Month);
```

Basically I'm pulling all of the date down, which works OK given the limited scope of this app. The TimeAdjust function gets "real" adjusted times, accounting for DLS. The ToArray() call is made to avoid the lazy execution that pisses of SQL because of the time adjustment function.

Comment: BTW timezone offsets should not be integer hours - there are fractional timezones.

Comment: Aware of that, but it's for US use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.MyRecords

    // tz adjusted, projection
   .Select(r => new {original = r.TimeStamp, adjusted = r.TimeStamp.AddHours(tz)})

   // group by start of month
   .GroupBy (r => r.adjusted.Date.AddDays(-r.Day))

   // final projection from groups to values asked for
   .Select (g => new {count = g.Count(), year = g.Key.Year, month = g.Key.Month})
```

Note: As @dana points out, if you want to account for daylight savings time too this is a whole lot more complex.  Grouping by offset times ignoring DST will get a good enough answer for most reports because the only values that will be wrongly accounted for are on month boundaries, around midnight for a few months of the year.

IF you do want to account for DST it's more complex than just looking at the date range and adding an extra hour.  Historically both the boundaries and the offsets of timezones have changed, so to do this right you need a historical record of these changes and you need to know the location of the user.  A simple TZ offset does not get you this.

IF you account for DST you also need to make sure you don't lose an hour or double count an hour twice a year.

It's nigh on impossible to get this 100% right if you account for DST which is why the TZ offset only approach is the better bet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the generated SQL does a bunch of nested conversions and gets milliseconds involved. That throws an error that says: "The datepart millisecond is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date." It's really a wild query (viewed in Profiler).

Comment: Any option to move to Entity Framework 4?  MSFT really beefed up the Date time functions in EF4. It might be better able to handle this than L2S now (haven't checked).  See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227648/how-to-add-day-to-date-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: I'd really like to avoid the EF if I can, because this little app will be used by some junior folk who will freak out at additional dependencies.

Comment: You could try converting it to a TimeSpan ys and use (t.TimeStamp + ts)??  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx has a list of what is *supposed* to work.

Comment: I'll mark this the answer, but I settled with the code in my edit.

Answer (score -2):

If you were using MySql, then you could use the function:

CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)

- converts a datetime value dt from the time zone given by from_tz to the time zone given by to_tz and returns the resulting value. Time zones are specified as described in Section 9.7, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”

Comment: Not useful, since the question was not about MySql.