# Comparing times with LINQ to sql dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

If I described right in the title, I want to query by datetime values just by hour and minute values.

In fact I want to filter rows on that day by hour of work or not.

I tried it with adding hours to pure date value

```
elementsOturums.Where(i => i.EntryTime.Value.AddDays(1) < i.EntryTime.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(8).AddMinutes(30)
                                                  && i.EntryTime.Value > i.EntryTime.Value.Date.AddHours(17).AddMinutes(15));
```

but it gave error like;

> The datepart millisecond is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.

Then I tried to overcome by using a method but again it gave an error like;

> Method '{0}' has no supported translation to SQL.

So how can I achieve this problem?

Comment: i.EntryTime.Value > i.EntryTime.Value.Date.AddHours(17).AddMinutes(15) this condition should not true.

Comment: You can't call methods that the data provider don't know how to translate it into SQL. Maybe you can just try .Where(i => i.EntryTime.Value.Hour < 8 && i.EntryTime.Value.Minute < 30  ...) like this.

Comment: [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227648/how-to-add-day-to-date-in-linq-to-sql) was asked before, the answers given there are useful for this problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare by TimeSpans:

```
var wdStart = TimeSpan.FromHours(8.5);
var wdEnd = TimeSpan.FromHours(17.25);

var result = elementsOturums.Where(t => t.EntryTime.HasValue)
    .Where(t => t.EntryTime.Value.TimeOfDay >= wdStart
             && t.EntryTime.Value.TimeOfDay <= wdEnd);
```

This gives you the items in working hours.