# Date and time range search

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I need to know the most efficient way to find all the database entries that fall in the time range for every day in a data range. Meaning if the data range is 7/20/2015 - 7/24/2015 and the time range is 1pm - 6pm. I need to look between 1pm - 6pm for each day in the date range.

Comment: Which sql are you using?

Comment: `SqlFunctions.DatePart()`, see duplicate.

Comment: First and foremost, you should make sure the associated columns in the database have indices defined for them. If you are using SQL Server, you can use the query optimization tool in SSMS to find the optimal index structure.

Comment: @ankit-bajpai I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: With LINQ-to-SQL you can do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31156923/861716).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
List<DayOfWeek> dayOfWeek = new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday};
int hourStart = 13;
int hourEnd = 18;
var a = new List<DateTime>();
a.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
a.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));
a.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3));
a.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4));
a.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5));
a.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).AddHours(5));
var result = a.Where(f => dayOfWeek.Contains(f.DayOfWeek) == true && (f.Hour >= hourStart && f.Hour <= hourEnd)).ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

```
List<DayOfWeek> dayOfWeek = new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday};
int hourStart = 13;
int hourEnd = 18; 
var result = Records.Where(f => dayOfWeek.Contains(f.DayOfWeek) == true && (f.Hour >= hourStart && f.Hour <= hourEnd)).ToList();
```